# select midi device in java

Tags: java, audio, midi

In my program it is necessary to be able to select the midi device in java.
I have tried using another sequencer that i got from `MidiSystem.getDevice()`.

Simply using `setSequence()` and starting the sequencer were without success however (i.e no sound).

I'm guessing that I somehow need to connect a Sequencer with a Synthesizer.

How can I do this properly?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038917/how-to-play-a-midi-file-in-a-new-thread-in-java