# How to get a reference to a non default MIDI Sequencer?

Tags: java, midi, javasound

I am building a Java application that programatically generates a MIDI Sequence that is then sent over the `LoopBe Internal Midi Port` so that I can use `Ableton Live` instruments for better sound playback quality.

Please correct me if I am wrong. What I need is to generate a `Sequence`, that will contain `Tracks` that will contains `MidiEvents`, that will contain `MIDI messages` with time information. That I think I got down.

**The real problem is how to send it over the LoopBe MIDI Port. For that I supposedly need a `Sequencer`, but I don't know how I can get one rather than the default one, and I don't want that.**

I guess a workaround would be to write the Sequence to a .mid file and then programatically play it back on the LoopBe Port.

So my question is: **How can I obtain a non-default Sequencer?**

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038917/how-to-play-a-midi-file-in-a-new-thread-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need method `MidiSystem.getSequencer(boolean)`. When you call it with `false` parameter, it gives you unconnected sequencer.

Get `Receiver` instance from your target MIDI device and set it to sequencer with `seq.getTransmitter().setReceiver(rec)` call.

Example snippet:

```
MIDIDevice device = ... // obtain the MIDIDevice instance
Sequencer seq = MidiSystem.getSequencer(false);
Receiver rec = device.getReceiver();
seq.getTransmitter().setReceiver(rec)
```

For examples on Sequencer use, see tutorial on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-seq-methods.html

Comment: Perfect. On mac one must use an external library such as 'coreMidi4j' to see all available external MIDI devices.

Answer (score 1):

For my own project I use LoopBe1 to send MIDI signals to REAPER.
Of course, LoopBe1 should already be installed.

In this example I iterate through the system's MIDI devices for the external MIDI port of LoopBe and then send the note C 10 times.

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MidiUnavailableException, InvalidMidiDataException, InterruptedException {
        MidiDevice external;

        MidiDevice.Info[] devices = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();

        //Iterate through the devices to get the External LoopBe MIDI port

        for (MidiDevice.Info deviceInfo : devices) {

            if(deviceInfo.getName().equals("LoopBe Internal MIDI")){
                if(deviceInfo.getDescription().equals("External MIDI Port")){
                    external = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(deviceInfo);
                    System.out.println("Device Name : " + deviceInfo.getName());
                    System.out.println("Device Description : " + deviceInfo.getDescription() + "\n");

                    external.open();
                    Receiver receiver = external.getReceiver();
                    ShortMessage message = new ShortMessage();


                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        // Start playing the note Middle C (60),
                        // moderately loud (velocity = 93).
                        message.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 0, 60, 93);
                        long timeStamp = -1;
                        receiver.send(message, timeStamp);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }

                    external.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For further information about the sending a MIDI signal, refer to this link:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-messages.html

I hope this helps!