# Playing music in a Java game

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to have some background music in a game I'm programming in Java. I have the coded, got no errors whatsoever.

The only problem is that no music plays.

Here's what I programmed:

```
import sun.audio.AudioData;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
import sun.audio.ContinuousAudioDataStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public void startBGMusic()

    try{

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("opening1.mid"));
        AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
         AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);

    }catch(Exception error){
          System.out.println("File Not Found");
          System.out.println(error);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you might wanna check this out as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038917/how-to-play-a-midi-file-in-a-new-thread-in-java

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class AudioTest{

    private static AudioStream theStream;

    //  Main method
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try{
            theStream = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("opening1.mid"));
            AudioPlayer.player.start(theStream);
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }//end main

}//end AudioTest class
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to strongly recommend using the javax.sound.sampled library for game audio. As far as I know these old sun.audio libraries are obsolete or deprecated or something. I don't use them at all, so I can't comment on how to work with them or whether code that works one one system will work on another. I don't think you can safely assume that it will.

The Java Tutorials [Trail: Sound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html) has what you need, although the tutorial is admittedly a difficult read.

The section on playing back sound will be the main point of focus.

Some folks make use of libraries, such as TinySound (available for free, on github), as a way to simplify game sf/x programming. You can find out more about it and other sf/x libraries on the java game programming site [java-gaming.org/](http://www.java-gaming.org/)

I find myself wondering why so many people end up trying to use these old sun libraries. Maybe it's just a side effect: the ones that do inevitably end up having problems and come asking questions on StackOverflow. As a result, that population of is "over-represented"?

Answer (score 0):

This method works perfectly for me, if it can help:

```
public synchronized void alarm(String audioString) 
{
    try
    {
        Clip crit = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource(audioString));
        crit.open(inputStream1);
        crit.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        crit.start();

    } catch (Exception e){System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
}
```

I found this code somewhere else on this website, just note it's not my idea, I'm not taking any credits for it.